# Accessibility issues in Table view cell subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility

I've been straggling with this issue for a while.
I have a table view cell, when selected, a subview containing some buttons is added to the cell.
Those buttons are not accessible via Voice Over.
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: unclear what you're asking.

Comment: some code might help? have you googled anything related to this to share with us so we don't start from the start?

Comment: Im not sure a code will help, most of it is defined in storyboard.
I have a search results table, when the user tap on one of the cells, i'm adding a subview to this cell with some buttons.
I wish to add accessibility to those buttons however when i tap on the cell the voice over keeps focusing on the cell and wont allow me to access the added button. 
hope this makes it a bit clearer..
Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much of a coding answer but...

You should be fine with what you got.
Safari and Mac VoiceOver can click buttons and links when focus is on a cell. Chrome and VO on the otherhand can not, but if you are a VO user you know that you might have to "interact" with some elements to reach a deeper interactive element. So if you use QuickNav and arrow Left + Down you can press the button in Chrome.

Tested with this code:

```
<table id="theTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Hey push it</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button type="button" id="pushMe">Push Me!</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and a lite jQuery to se if somethings happend:

```
$('#pushMe').on('click',function(e){
  $('#theTable').css('background','red');
});
```

Test for yourself on CodePen: [Screen Reader and Table test](http://codepen.io/DanielGoransson/pen/kidzH)